# How do I do an ajax call using jQuery to an MVC3 controller using the following

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an input

```
<input type="button" id="test" value="test" />
```

My action on the 'Home' controller:

```
public ActionResult DataUsage(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string userName)
{
  var data = FetchDataFromDB(startDate, endDate, uName);
  return PartialView("DataUsageChartViewPartial", data);
}
```

The div I want to load the result form DataUsage in

```
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

jQuery code

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
               url: '/Home/DataUsage',
               type: 'POST',
               data: { startDate: $('#startDate').val(), endDate: $('#endDate').val(), userName: $('#userName').val() },
               success: function (result) {
                   alert("success " +result);
              },
              error: function (err) {
                 alert("error "+err);
             }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
 );
```

When I click the button I want the div(myChart) to be populated with the result from the action in the controller.
I'm not sure if my jQuery is correct as I keep getting an error and the breakpoint in my controller/action is never hit.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it

Comment: have you added [HttpPost] on action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maurice,

I think it could well be a very simple case of not having the correct url being called. You should try using the helpers in mvc:

```
url: '@Url.Action("DataUsage", "Home")'
```

Also, you might want to decorate your action with HttpPost to ensure that it's in step with your ajax type, i.e:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DataUsage(...)
```

this should take you one step closer, if not solve the issue completely.

The final step is to ensure that you have a div called 'myChart' inside your 'calling' view, then populate it as thus:

```
<div id='myChart'></div>

success: function (result) {
    $('#myChart').html(result);
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the format of the date you entered in the textbox is correct and matches your server side culture settings. For example depending on the culture your application is configured to, 12/15/2012 and 15/12/2012 might indicate the same date to the user depending on where he comes from and yet the default model binder will use the current culture settings.

Also to debug those kind of problems please use a javascript debugging tools such as FireBug and inspect the AJAX request. If you had done that you would have seen the exact error message sent from the server which in your case should be something long the lines of: *`15/12/2012` is not a valid DateTime*.

Answer (score 1):

Dude the issue in your code for the starters is that you have specified Post method for the Ajax to call the controller , whereas as per your code which you have put shows that the method is available in get method .
Simplest way out is put `[HttpPost]` annotation on the controller action method.

i.e the method in your controller looks like :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DataUsage(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string userName)
{
  var data = FetchDataFromDB(startDate, endDate, uName);
  return PartialView("DataUsageChartViewPartial", data);
}
```

So this will solve the problem of the breakpoint not getting called.

Other thing suggested is always user Url.Action(...) Method when you want to give urls to be called from ajax or wherever . Else it may create problems when deployed etc.